# PHP/Javascript - Parsing html from my University Website

Tags: php, javascript, parsing

I'm trying to parse the courses from this page: http://college.usc.edu/cf/course-guide/genelects.cfm. Specifically, the category II courses.

I'm not too familiar with the javascript, but it seems that when the cat II link is clicked, this method is called:

```
function GetClassList(catid,sem,semester)
{
  jQuery('#FallClasses_'+catid).hide();
  jQuery('#SpringClasses_'+catid).toggle();
  jQuery('#SpringClasses_'+catid).load('genelects-ajax-getclasslist.cfm', {catid:catid,sem:sem});
}
```

The problem is I don't see the courses anywhere in the html. It seems to all be done on the server side.

---

EDIT!

So I found where in the DOM the data is being placed. I used firebug.

I looked at the DOM associated with this div:

```
<div id="SpringClasses_2" style="display: none; "/>
```

Then in the Firebug DOM tab, I:

```
1) Clicked +children.
2) Found the html I need under +innerHTML.
```

---

I understand now how to find the data. But I need to write a script (run on another domain) to parse that DOM. **How can I do this? How can I get that DOM from the college page, and then parse it?**

Comment: DOM changes won't be shown in the 'view source' html; if you use Firebug for Firefox, or Web Inspector for Chrome, it'll allow you to see changes to the DOM live/in realtime.

Comment: The class list seems to be loaded via Ajax (`jQuery().load()`). You might be able to directly send a request to `genelects-ajax-getclasslist.cfm` with the right category ID and retrieve the list.

Comment: @Felix: I tried /genelects-ajax-getclasslist.cfm?catid=2&sem=20111. (Parameters taken from the course.) It didn't work.

Comment: This was the url I tried without success: http://college.usc.edu/cf/course-guide/genelects-ajax-getclasslist.cfm?catid=2&sem=20111

Comment: @Felix - it POSTs the data, which makes things more difficult.  Trying to do it via GET (e.g. http://college.usc.edu/cf/course-guide/genelects-ajax-getclasslist.cfm?catid=1&sem=20111) doesn't work.

Comment: Well, this gets something `$.post('http://college.usc.edu/cf/course-guide/genelects-ajax-getclasslist.cfm', {catid:2,sem:20111});` (sic)

Comment: @passcod - perhaps you should put that as an answer :)  I would have thought that the same domain policy would prevent that.

Comment: @Danny Anges, @El Yobo: I know that it is a POST request. But you can also make on in PHP with `curl` so I see no problem in getting the information. How do you want to parse the information anyway? I thought (as the question is tagged `php`) you want to parse the HTML with PHP...

Comment: @Danny, have you considered getting permission to the database itself?  Or, talking them into modifying their code to return JSON if a variable such as `json=1` is included in the post?

Comment: @Felix King: Sorry, I do want to parse it with PHP. Can you show me how I can do that with curl?

Comment: @Danny Anges: Well with curl you can just get the HTML, then you need some HTML parser for extracting the information. As a start, search for `php curl post` and `php html parser`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code might look like:

```
function GetClassList(catid,sem,semester)
{
  $('#FallClasses_'+catid).hide();
  $('#SpringClasses_'+catid).toggle();

    $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'genelects-ajax-getclasslist.cfm',
                data: 'catid='+encodeURIComponent(catid)+'&sem='+encodeURIComponent(sem),
                success: function(data){
                jQuery('#SpringClasses_'+catid).html(data);
                }
        });
}
```

Just be careful that `genelects-ajax-getclasslist.cfm` script returns only html data you'd like to put into `#SpringClasses_'+catid` container.
The script `genelects-ajax-getclasslist.cfm` should be located on the same Internet domain as this javascript source, of course, in other words should be local, not a remote one.

Comment: But I don't have access to that internet domain. I'm trying to parse this data from the university's domain.

Comment: You can make your own php parser that will extract only the teble rows you need (you could ask here for guidelines) and use it as url in the ajax call

Answer (score 0):

I would have probably acted differently...
*(i.e. a small php or perl command line client parsing with regexps)*

But given what you got, you can add a hidden form of yours to that page and use an `<input>` element to store the data you obtain with javascript. Then, `submit()` it to a server you control. Even a local one. Even on localhost.

AFAIK, no obscure security mechanism should be triggered, this way.

IIRC something like

```
var input=$('<input name="data" value=""/>')
var form=$('<form style="display:none"
                  action="http://myserver.example.com/post-junk-here.php"
                  method="post">
            <input type="submit">
            </form>')

$('html').append(form.append(input))
input.value=my_hard_earned_data
form.submit()
```

should do it.